# How 'Office.addin.setStartupBehavior(Office.StartupBehavior.load);' works?

Tags: office-js

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio IDE to develop the office web addin. My questions are all about 'Office.addin.setStartupBehavior(Office.StartupBehavior.load);' method.

1. Where should I call this method in Visual Studio project?
2. When this method would be triggered on the client side (in production)?
3. After installing the addin, does the below code in the addin executes whenever we open any workbook?

   ```
    Office.initialize = () => {Excel.run(async context => {await context.sync();});};
   ```
4. My addin is a task pane type and I wish to show the task pane on a specific event. When 'Office.initialize' function executes on document load then the task pane does not show up?

Thanks,
Naveen Kumar

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/run-code-on-document-open

Comment: Thanks Rick. The link does not tell where exactly to set the startup behavior. It tells what happens or what we can do when we configure the add-in to load when the document opens. But, it does not tell where to set the load behavior.

Comment: I think it is saying that you set the behavior with the parameter that you pass to the method. To set it to load on startup, pass the `load` value of the `Office.StartupBehavior` enum: `Office.addin.setStartupBehavior(Office.StartupBehavior.load);`

Answer (score 0):

From my observations and after digging around,

> 1. Where should I call this method in Visual Studio project?

Anywhere within a block where Office has already been loaded. Any javascript (or typescript) file included in the project will usually have Office define since the library is included in the head of the HTML template by default first.

> 2. When this method would be triggered on the client side (in production)?

It will be triggered as it is invoked. As soon the compiler hits it, the settings of the document are changed.

> 3. After installing the addin, does the below code in the addin executes whenever we open any workbook?

No, the bellow code executes only for workbooks that have run the add-in at least once. Office add-ins are not installed by default for every workbook; every workbook must download the add-in at start-up.

> My addin is a task pane type and I wish to show the task pane on a specific event. When 'Office.initialize' function executes on document load then the task pane does not show up?

To show the taskpane, you must use the API call:

```
Office.addin.showAsTaskpane();
```

To close the taskpane, use:

```
Office.addin.hide();
```

If you want to open the taskpane on specific event, do the following:

- First, add Worksheet Event Listener on document open by including it into an onReady function (preferred, see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/initialize-add-in).
- For the event listener you set, invoke showAsTaskpane()

Sample code:

```
Office.onReady(() => {
    Office.addin.setStartupBehavior(Office.StartupBehavior.load); // so that event listener is invoked next time the document starts
    let sheets = context.workbook.worksheets;
        sheets[onEventName].add(async (eventData: any) => {
             // EXECUTE YOUR EVENT HANDLER HERE
        });
      }
});
```